# Is there a way to replace all first paragraphs after a page break with that same content but in bold?

Tags: microsoft-word

Basically what is said in the title: I've got a very long document with no formatting and lots and lots of page breaks and I would like to format the first paragraph after each page break in bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on Wildcard in Advanced Find and enter the search term below.

> ^m^13*^13

Click the "Find in" drop-down menu and click "Main Document." This will highlight all manual line breaks, the next closest line space, and all the text in between (as shown in the screenshot below). With all of that highlighted, just select boldface and that should do it.
[image]

Comment: +1 This is awesome. Where can I find the description for `^m^13*^13` wild card to understand?

Comment: @Prasanna This is one of the more comprehensive and useful guides I've come across: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm.